# Automate an excel report

Tags: excel, email

this is my first post here and I hope its not to noobish. Im an analytics intern at a health system and I have a weekly report on wed mornings. This week I automated the SQL query to run through SAP so all I do to this thing is hit refresh all on the data tab in excel and email it. I would like to maybe take it a step farther and refresh the spreadsheet at a time after the query runs at 6am and send the email too its recipients. My coding knowledge is vba/SQL for work but im confident on my fundamentals to hop into new spaces. Can you guys point me in a direction on how to fully automate this process?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to create a VBScript and invoke it with Windows Task Scheduler: http://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/excel-running-excel-on-windows-task.html

Comment: "im confident on my fundamentals to hop into new spaces." Like+1